# TypeScript unable to load / use table2excel

Tags: jquery, typescript, sharepoint-online

I'm using this [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/table2excel) in my TypeScript webpart for SharePoint Online

I've included `jquery` and `table2excel` in the script and everything not related to `table2excel` is working fine.

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
require('table2excel');
```

I have installed 'table2excel' by using `npm i table2excel`

Then when I try to use `table2excel` it returns the following error:
```

> $(...).table2excel is not a function
>   ```

```
(<any>$("#ViewTablehidden")).table2excel({
    exclude: ".noExl",
    name: "title",
    filename: "title",
    fileext: ".xls",
    exclude_img: true,
    exclude_links: true,
    exclude_inputs: true
});
```

Why can't I get it to work?

Comment: this? // npm install table2excel --save
import 'table2excel';
const Table2Excel = window.Table2Excel;
 
const table2excel = new Table2Excel(options);

Comment: @Cristian not working, It says, Property ' table2excel' does not exist on type window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pulling in the wrong package. You need to use [`jquery-table2excel`](https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel) instead of `table2excel`.

It looks like the NPM packages times out. The package is available through Bower (which you can ref as an import) or you can link directly to CDN assets. Here's an [example](https://codepen.io/kieran/pen/wxRBmO) to show you with import directly from URL.

```js
$('#download').on('click', function(){
  $(".table2excel").table2excel({
    exclude: ".noExl",
    name: "Excel Document Name",
    filename: "myExcelFile.xls",
    fileext: ".xls",
    exclude_img: true,
    exclude_links: true,
    exclude_inputs: true
  });  
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table thead tr th {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 5px;
}

button {
  background: navy;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>

<table class="table2excel" data-tableName="Test Table 1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="noExl"><th>This shouldn't get exported</th><th>This shouldn't get exported either</th></tr>
    <tr><th>This Should get exported as a header</th><th>This should too</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data1a with a <a href="#">link one</a> and <a href="#">link two</a>.</td>
      <td>data1b with a <img src="image_file.jpg" alt="image">.</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2a with a <input tyle="text" value="text value">.</td>
      <td>data2b with a <input tyle="text" value="second text value">.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr><td colspan="2">This footer spans 2 cells</td></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<table class="table2excel" data-tableName="Test Table 2">
  <thead>
    <tr class="noExl"><td>This shouldn't get exported</td><td>This shouldn't get exported either</td></tr>
    <tr><td>This Should get exported as a header</td><td>This should too</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>data1a</td><td>data1b</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data2a</td><td>data2b</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr><td colspan="2">This footer spans 2 cells</td></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<button id="download">Download</button>
```

or using `table2excel` (not the jQuery plugin)

install

```
npm i table2excel --save
```

use

```
import 'table2excel';

const Table2Excel = window.Table2Excel;

const table2excel = new Table2Excel({
  exclude: ".noExl",
  name: "Excel Document Name",
  filename: "myExcelFile",
  exclude_img: true,
  exclude_links: true,
  exclude_inputs: true
});

table2excel.export(document.querySelector('.table2excel'));
```

Comment: When I use the following line `import 'table2excel';` I get this error: `Unexpected anonymous AMD define`

Comment: I'ts not posible to post a snippet since this is a SharePoint framework problem with importing npm files.

Comment: This library is a jquery plugin, so you can not import `table2excel`. Moreover, no need to import though

Comment: I provided a secondary example using the NPM lib. The NPM package is not a jQuery plugin. It's a standalone version of the `table2excel` library.